# Change Time & Calender to English

Tags: 16.04, indicator, time

I have installed "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"in My Lenovo-E40-70 laptop 
And Location I choose Riyadh Saudi Arabia. I'm getting Calender and time in Arabic not English.

How do I change to English?

Answer (score 2):

click on system settings.

[image]

Click on Language Support.

[image]

Click on the Regional Formats Tab, and change language to English, and apply system- wide. and that will do it.

Note: You may have to reboot, so changes can take effect

[image]

Comment: Dear I am trying to install vmware, But getting failed. -Lenovo-E40-70:~/Downloads$ VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.6-1035888.x86_64.bundle
VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.6-1035888.x86_64.bundle: command not found

Comment: Dear, Thanks for the support to change the time from Arabic to English...Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look at it for vmware https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Workstation

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to change language in Ubuntu, First of all Go to System Settings, then to Language Support. From there open the second tab which is 
named "Regional Formats". Then change the drop down bar's content from "Arabic" to the English language variant you like and you're all set.

Re-login for this to take effect

Comment: Dear, Thanks for your Help. I am getting Error While performing this task...

Comment: what's the error you are getting